# Months not being combined in Count Case When statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Statement and I would like the months of the year to be combined. My `query` is splitting the months up and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.OPENED) AS MonthName, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Commercial, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 END) AS Residential
FROM     hb_Disputes CROSS JOIN
              Users
WHERE  (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE = 'Ian Mark') AND (YEAR(hb_Disputes.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY
hb_Disputes.OPENED
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Include month in `Group By` statement.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.OPENED) AS MonthName, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Commercial, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 END) AS Residential
FROM     hb_Disputes CROSS JOIN
              Users
WHERE  (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE = 'Ian Mark') AND (YEAR(hb_Disputes.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY
hb_Disputes.OPENED,
DATENAME(MONTH, hb_Disputes.OPENED)
```

Comment: @IanMark There was typo, I have corrected it. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Group by exactly the expession you want to have a single row for each value in the result set.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, '2001-' + cast(DATEPART(MM, hb_Disputes.OPENED) as char(2)) +'-01' ) AS MonthName, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Commercial, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 END) AS Residential
FROM     hb_Disputes CROSS JOIN
              Users
WHERE  (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE = 'Ian Mark') AND (YEAR(hb_Disputes.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, hb_Disputes.OPENED)
ORDER BY DATEPART(MM, hb_Disputes.OPENED)
```

**EDIT**

If you need data ordered by month number then group by month number. Show month name as a function of month number in `select`. See above.
You can also use plain `case` to decode a month number to its name.

Comment: I've tried this before and it's giving me the months in alphabetical order, not in the order of a normal calendar. Even if it showed 1,2,3 as the months would be fine I just need them in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

Month name needed to be removed and replaced with numeric values:

```
SELECT MONTH (hb_Disputes.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Commercial, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 END) AS Residential
FROM            hb_Disputes CROSS JOIN
                     Users
WHERE        (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE = 'Ian Mark') AND 
(YEAR(hb_Disputes.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE()))

GROUP BY
MONTH (hb_Disputes.OPENED)
```